# Expected expression before 'typeof' OR expected primary-expression before 'typeof'

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I have a macro like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#define m_test_type(e)                              \
    do {                                            \
         if (typeof(e) == typeof(char [])) {        \
            printf("type is char []\n");            \
         } else                                     \
         if (typeof(e) == typeof(int)) {            \
            printf("type is int\n");                \
         } else {                                   \
            printf("type is unknown\n");            \
         }                                          \
     } while (0)

int main() {
    char s[] = "hello";

    m_test_type(s);

    return 0;
}
```

During compilation with gcc I get following error:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:6:14: error: expected primary-expression before 'typeof'
          if (typeof(e) == typeof(char *)) {         \
              ^
prog.cpp:19:2: note: in expansion of macro 'm_test_type'
  m_test_type(s);
  ^
prog.cpp:6:14: error: expected ')' before 'typeof'
          if (typeof(e) == typeof(char *)) {         \
              ^
prog.cpp:19:2: note: in expansion of macro 'm_test_type'
  m_test_type(s);
  ^
prog.cpp:9:14: error: expected primary-expression before 'typeof'
          if (typeof(e) == typeof(int)) {            \
              ^
prog.cpp:19:2: note: in expansion of macro 'm_test_type'
  m_test_type(s);
  ^
prog.cpp:9:14: error: expected ')' before 'typeof'
          if (typeof(e) == typeof(int)) {            \
              ^
prog.cpp:19:2: note: in expansion of macro 'm_test_type'
  m_test_type(s);
  ^
```

Comment: `typeof` is not standard C, it's a [GNU extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) in GCC. What compiler are you using?

Comment: i'm using gcc compiler

Comment: Code must take a SWAG at what `e` is. It has no way of knowing and neither does `typeof`.

Comment: `typeof` does not produce a value, it produces a type. You cannot compare types. For example `if (int == int)` is an invalid comparison.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin [SWAG?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_wild-ass_guess) English, please.

Comment: Swinging Wild Ass Guess....

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you can use **typeof** to test for type equality. If you look at the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html), `typeof (expr)` is statically replaced by the type of the expression, which allows you to declare variables :

```
int i;
typeof(&i) p;
```

In that case the last instruction will be equivalent to `int* p;`

However if you use `typeof` in an if statement like yours would be an error since it would be equivalent to write something like

```
if ( char* == char *)
```

which is causing the error.

Answer (score 4):

This is not standard C, so it will only compile with GCC setup to be a non-standard compiler. Meaning you probably shouldn't use options like `-std=c11` or `-pedantic` to make this compile. I would not recommend that though.

I would instead recommend to get rid of all non-standard GCC crap and write pure standard C instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define m_test_type(e)                     \
  printf(_Generic((e),                     \
           char*:   "type is char*\n",     \
           int:     "type is int\n",       \
           default: "type is unknown\n"    \
         ));

int main() {
    char s[] = "hello";

    m_test_type(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i can run this code now by using [builtin functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.5/gcc/Other-Builtins.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define m_test_type(e)                                                   \
    do {                                                                 \
         if (__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(e), typeof(char []))) { \
            printf("type is char []\n");                                 \
         } else                                                          \
         if (__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(e), typeof(int))) {     \
            printf("type is int\n");                                     \
         } else {                                                        \
            printf("type is unknown\n");                                 \
         }                                                               \
     } while (0)

int main() {
    const char s[] = "hello";

    m_test_type(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But you are printing `"type is char *\n"` when the type is actually `char []`. For example, `m_test_type(char *);` and `m_test_type(&s[0]);` both print `"type is unknown\n"`. Like `sizeof(x)`, `typeof(x)` is one of those places where an array `x` does not decay to a pointer `&(x)[0]`.

Comment: thank you for the comment, it was juste a copy/paste error, i ve fixed it now